# Remove yellow class name popup (breadcrumb) from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, editor, preferences

I just want to get rid of these yellow rects that keep popping up in IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: breadcrumb]

Comment: you mean unused code ?

Comment: They're just those pop ups. They represent the class I'm in.

Comment: BTW, the yellow breadcrumb is a bug caused by your dark theme inherited from the `Default` theme instead of `Darcula`, see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160573#comment=27-1597067) for the fix. They would be darker with the proper editor theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "class name popups" are actually called [breadcrumbs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-adds-breadcrumb-for-java/) and can include other things such as method names.  They're clickable and used to ease navigation.  You can disable them in the IntelliJ `Preferences` by going to `Editor -> General -> Appearance` and unchecking `Show breadcrumbs`.  See my image below.

[image]