# How to remove the structure bar under the file tabs in PyCharm 2017?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I want hide the structure bar under the file tabs in PyCharm 2017.

When I change my cursor position it's will be change too, and very disturbing my attention.

I spent half a hour to find the setting but failed, please tell me how can I hide it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove yellow class name popup (breadcrumb) from IntelliJ IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616133/remove-yellow-class-name-popup-breadcrumb-from-intellij-idea)

Comment: @yole thanks, it's works.